# Sending AJAX call to a php file to INSERT a value into my database

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, prepared-statement

I   I have a db table called user_requests where I have a column called 'status'. I output the status' on the page userRequests.php. I output all of the user requests via while loops. What I am trying to accomplish is being able to hit the button 'approve' or 'deny' to change the 'status' in my user_requests table. I am trying to do this with AJAX and this is my first attempt at making an AJAX call. When I click on approve I want it to grab the id of the user I selected Accept next to and then carry the value of 'Accept' and `INSERT`that into my user_requests db table in the 'status' row.

As I have it now nothing happens at all. Does anyone see anything wrong with how how I am trying to do this?

userRequests.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($run);

    if( $numrows ) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            if($row['status'] == "Pending"){

                $pending_id         = $row['id'];
                $pending_user_id   = $row['user_id'];
                $pending_firstname = $row['firstname'];
                $pending_lastname  = $row['lastname'];
                $pending_username  = $row['username'];
?>
        <form action="" method="POST" id="status">
             <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $pending_id; ?>' id='pending_id'/>
<?php
        if ($pending_firstname == true) {
            echo "Name - ". $pending_firstname . " " . $pending_lastname . "</br>" . 
                "Username - ". $pending_username . "</br></br>"
?>
        </form>

                        <button id="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" value="Approved">Approve</button>
                        <button id="deny" type="submit" form="status" name="deny" value="Denied">Deny</button><br><br><br>
<?php   
                    ;} else {
                        echo "There are no Pending Requests at this time.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

AJAX call

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(){
    var id_val=$("#pending_id").val();
    var id_val=$("#approve").val();
    $.post("userRequest_approve.php", $("#status").serialize(),  function(data) {   });

    $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
    $('#success').hide(2000);

    });

    });
</script>
```

userRequest_approve.php file

```
 <?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$term = mysql_escape_string($term); // Attack Prevention
$pending_id = $_POST['id'];
$status = $_POST['approve'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_requests (status, date_responded) VALUES (?, NOW())");
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User Request update prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $status);
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('User Request update bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
        die('User Status update execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }

?>
```

Comment: $('#submit').click(function(){...... i dont see any ID="submit" so your click is on the wrong ID unless im missing some code here

Comment: @lauw Good catch. I fixed that and now I am getting my success message from my AJAX call, but nothing is changing in my db.

Comment: Your javascript code does not make sense. You define `var id_val` twice, where the 2nd value over writes the 1st. And then you never do anything with `var id_val`. Then you have `$("#status").serialize()` in your `$.post`, but since your `<form action="" method="POST" id="status">` is done in a loop, you will have `n` number of `#status` (where `id`s are supposed to be unique) so how is javascript to know which `#status` form data you want?

Comment: Also, `#pending_id` and `#approve` have the same issue.  You have `n` number of each,  so which one should javascript select,  as it will always find the first, not the one related to the button you click.

Comment: @Sean I wasn't sure if the value from the button Approve's value 'Approved' would send or how to make it. That's why I did `var id_val=$("#approve").val();` I just tried changing it to `var val=$("#approve").val();`, but that didn't help. I change want the button's value of 'Approved' to send over and be inserted into that user's ID.

Comment: @Sean How am I able to relate the id to the call I am trying to make then? This is the part I really don't get.

Comment: hey paul.... your trying to approved 1 user by 1 user right.... not an entire batch....so... first of all make your ID a CLASS.... then when they click on the class you select the value of that single row.... i will adept my answer in a second so you can use it

Comment: @lauw The new changes still aren't doing anything? Are you sure my php file isn't causing nothing to change. Would this line be right? `$status = $_POST['approve'];`

Comment: @paul, the best way to test if it actually arrives is make a new php file that only echo's 'hai' for example so.... url: '/newFile.php' (just make sure your URL is pointing to correct file)

Answer (score 3):

I think you javascript is the weakest part of your code, here is some simple example for your ajax call, just change some values around and try it out

```
$('.approve').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: '/whereEver/itNeedsToGo',
           data: {
                id: $(this).val(), //the value of what you clicked on
                status: 'Approved' //you clicked on it so you know the status might aswell hardcode it
            },
           success: function(data) {
                //do something with the data that got returned
           },
           type: 'POST'
        });
});
```

EDIT: i would make it a little "dirty" to achief what you want... there are more ways to solve it but for now i will do it the easy way....
change ID into class
`<button class="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" value="<?=$pending_id;?>">Approve</button>` give the approve button the value of the pending ID..... and i edit the ajax call above accordingly....this should work

Comment: I need to carry over the id of the user I am selecting 'Accept' next to.

Comment: something like this... i made some changes for you..... you might need jquery library incase thats not included in your code

Comment: Didn't do anything. Is my userRequest_approve.php file allowing the values to pass through and send or is that causing this to stop there?

Comment: @paul.... please do check if you have JQuery included.... it might need that.....your userRequest_approve.php should accept it... there is actually 1 easy way to find out print_r($_POST) and see what happends if in your jquery when you do.... success: function(data) {alert(data) } it should print out whatever you printed in your PHP

Comment: you can't use the same id for multiple elements. so pending_id would not work for more than 1, you can always use it as a class instead and sort out (not recommended), use a custom variable like data-request-id (best imo), or append something to the id (pending_id_##, easy also) to make it unique.

Comment: I do have the jquery library in my file 1.11.2.....I get this to print out `Array ( ) 1` for each of the users that are in my db.